# IDictionary of class displayed in a table c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, idictionary

I have an `IDictionary` which holds an ever changing list of my class and I want to display the collection in a winforms UI probably using `DataGridView` or another control. I plan to have timer that refreshes the table every 1 to 2 seconds and a pause button. when any given row is clicked I need to be able to get the class from the dictionary or return the first field which be the key in the `IDictionary`.

So I create the `IDictionary` thus:

```
public static IDictionary<string, AClass> aList = new Dictionary<string, AClass>();
```

`AClass` is a simple collection of strings:

```
public class AClass
{
    public string data1{ get; set; }
    public string data2{ get; set; }
}
```

I add the `AClass` to the `IDictionary` thus:

```
 if (!MainForm.aircraftList.ContainsKey(strMyData))
        {
            MainForm.aList[strMyData] = new AClass{ data1= strMyData};
        }
```

How can I create the table with all the columns from `AClass` which are around 12 and rows from the `IDictionary` aList of which there is a variable number hovering around 100.

Comment: I am guessing you want to display this data into a `DataGridView`?

Comment: Yes that would be good, but if there is a better control i'm not tied to using it.

Comment: It appears a `DataGridView` will work to display your data. If you are using a class, then I would recommend either a simple `List` or better yet a `DataTable` to hold the data then set the `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` to this `List/DataTable`. If you use a `Dictionary` for this, you may have to go through some extra steps to get the data to display properly.

Comment: Do you just want to display the properties of AClass, or do you also want to display the dictionary key for each AClass?

Comment: just the properties is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To possibly help you get started, below is code that uses a `DataGridView` to display data using a `DataTable`; a `List<AClass>` objects and also using a `Dictionary<string, AClass>`. As I said using a dictionary, you will have to do some extra steps to get the `AClass` `Value` from the dictionary. These extra steps indicate that the Dictionary is not necessarily the best data structure to use as a `DataSource` if there a multiple variables in your class.

The code below uses a `DataGridView` and four (4) buttons. There are buttons to display data into the `DataGridView` using a `DataTable`; a `List<AClass>` (added a key), and a `Dictionary<string, AClass>` and finally a button to clear the `DataGridView`

Hope this helps.

```
public Dictionary<string, AClass> DGVDictionary;
public DataTable DGVTable;
public List<AClass> DGVList;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private Dictionary<string, AClass> GetDictionary() {
  Dictionary<string, AClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, AClass>();
  for (int key = 0; key < 15; key++) {
    AClass ac = new AClass();
    ac.data1 = "data1" + key;
    ac.data2 = "data2" + key;
    dictionary.Add(key.ToString(), ac);
  }
  return dictionary;
}

private void CreateTable() {
  DGVTable = new DataTable();
  DGVTable.Columns.Add("key", typeof(int));
  DGVTable.Columns.Add("data1", typeof(string));
  DGVTable.Columns.Add("data2", typeof(string));
}

private void FillDataTable() {
  for (int key = 0; key < 15; key++) {
    AClass ac = new AClass();
    ac.data1 = "data1" + key;
    ac.data2 = "data2" + key;
    DGVTable.Rows.Add(key, ac.data1, ac.data2);
  }
}

private List<AClass> FillList() {
  List<AClass> list = new List<AClass>();
  for (int key = 0; key < 15; key++) {
    AClass ac = new AClass();
    ac.key = key;
    ac.data1 = "data1" + key;
    ac.data2 = "data2" + key;
    list.Add(ac);
  }
  return list;
}

 private void buttonDataTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CreateTable();
  FillDataTable();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = DGVTable;
  MessageBox.Show("DGV with a DataTable");
}

private void buttonList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DGVList = FillList();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = DGVList;
  MessageBox.Show("DGV with a List<AClass>");
}

private void buttonDictionary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DGVDictionary = GetDictionary();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = DGVDictionary.ToList();
  MessageBox.Show("DGV with a Dictionat<string, AClass>");
}

private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you John I will play with this and try see how i can use this approach too.

Comment: in the function buttonDataTable_Click is there a way of making it show the key and one of the values in the class say data2?

Comment: The `buttonDataTable_Click` event is made to specifically get and fill the `DatGridView` you could easily change this to look for what ever key value pair you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an IDictionary, the default binding mechanism will not be able to retrieve the individual entries nor the properties on the class AClass.  You can create a custom [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle these tasks.

The primary responsibility of custom BingSource is to supply a collection of ProperyDescriptors for the AClass type.  These are retrieved using the [TypeDescriptor.GetProperties Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getproperties(v=vs.110).aspx).  The BindingSource also needs to access the underlying DataSource items by index; this is handled in the indexer of the BindingSource.

To use this BindingSource, create an instance of it passing your IDictionary instance and then assign this BindingSource to the DataGridView's DataSource property.

```
internal class myBindingSource : BindingSource
    {
    private IDictionary<string, AClass> source;
    private System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection props;

    public myBindingSource(IDictionary<string, AClass> source)
        {
        this.source = source;
        props = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(AClass));
        this.DataSource = source;
        }

    public override System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
        return props;
        }

    public override object this[int index]
        {
        get {return this.source.Values.ElementAtOrDefault(index);}
        set {}
        }

    public override bool AllowNew
        {
        get { return false; }
        set{}
        }

    public override bool AllowEdit
        {
        get { return false; }
        }

    public override bool AllowRemove
        {
        get {return false;}
        }

    public override int Count
        {
        get {return ((this.source == null) ? -1 : this.source.Count);}
        }
    }
```

Edit:  I have added an override of the Count property to the code to allow the the [BindingSource.ResetBindings Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx) to work properly when called to force the bound control to re-read the values from the BindingSource. I have also updated the indexer code.

If you modify the custom BindingSource's underlying DataSource after assigning it as the DataGridView's DataSource, you will need to call the BindingSource.ResetBindings method for those changes to be reflected in the grid.

For Example:

```
    private IDictionary<string, AClass> aList;
    private myBindingSource bs;

    public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        aList = new Dictionary<string, AClass>();

        bs = new myBindingSource(aList);
        dgv.DataSource = bs;

        aList.Add("1", new AClass());
        aList.Add("2", new AClass { data1 = "AA", data2 = "BB" });
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
        }
```

Comment: thank you for this, a lot of it is beyond me, however i have added it and it does add all the names across the top of the datagrdiview . I create it before filling the list as the form loads. how do i make it up date the data following each time i add or remove items to the dictionary?

Comment: actually I can't get it to show the data only the properties names on a header row not the data in each row below it.

Comment: @Adrian,  I updated my answer and provided a short example.  The code also has some minor changes to handle what I think you want to do.

Comment: thank you for help and this would seem a good solution however i not get it to show the data so went with the other answer.